# Parallax malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, parallax

I'm trying to implement a parallax using vanilla javascript. But I don't want to use the property `backgroundPositionY`. I want it to be implemented using `transform:'translate3d()';` but the issue is it is moving the entire container rather than the background image and creating a space between the parallax and paragraph as shown below.
Here is my code: https://codepen.io/harshal-sharma/pen/qBEXXqX
So far I have tried using `::before` pseudo-element to separate the background image and the content but I am unable to perform javascript manipulation to pseudo-element and they cannot be used for adding nested content.

The approaches I took:

```
        .parallax{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden
  }
  .parallax::before{
   content:"";
   position:absolute;
   height:980px;
   width:100%;
   z-index:-1;
   background:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537210249814-b9a10a161ae4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80");
   background-attachment:fixed;
   }
```

And

```
   var P = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax");
   var style = document.createElement('style');
   style.innerHTML = 'background:url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1537210249814-b9a10a161ae4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80")';
   document.para.insertBefore(style);
```

but getting a error. **Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'insertBefore' of undefined**
Please ignore any syntactical typos.

Comment: Can you please show what exactly you are getting for error here

Comment: @AlanM I have shared my code expand the output the code is giving and try scrolling. You'll see a gap being created between parallax and paragraph due to scrolling which doesn't happen when ```backgroundPositionY``` is used. Edited the error part.